# Integrate Mirth Connect with Splunk

Tags: javascript, splunk, mirth

I want to push the logs that we generate in the Mirth to Splunk, I am not able to find if there is some direct way in which mirth logged errors can be pushed to Splunk dashboards. I am open to indirect but efficient ways of doing this if direct integration is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Mirth, but do a lot of onboarding of data into Splunk.  There are a few options:

1. Install the Splunk Universal Forwarder to monitor Mirth logs and push them to Splunk.  The UF should be installed on the server running Mirth.
2. Send Mirth logs as syslog to a syslog server and then on to Splunk.
3. Send Mirth logs directly to Splunk using HTTP Event Collector.

There are other methods, but they probably don't apply.